# Nodejs. Asynchronous Encryption and Decryption

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, encryption

I was wondering why there isn't any async function for encryption & decryption on the native nodejs crypto module or any other modules i failed to find.
Either symmetric or asymmetric.

I want to use this functionallity on a server request, and was worried about blocking and slowing the server on a large scale of requests if it'll not be async.

Maybe my worries are too many, and the intensity of the the encrypt/decrypt process isn't too much.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possibility you have to obtain async Encryption/Decryption is to delegate these operations to another process. The only async operations you can do in nodejs are I/O operations while pure computation operations will block your process until they have finished. Remember that node is single-thread.

Comment: Thanks, that was my goto solution if indeed there is no such async functionality. using [compute-cluster](https://github.com/lloyd/node-compute-cluster).

Answer (score 1):

While Node's event loop is single-threaded, Node can easily call into a C binding running in Node's thread pool. This gives you the best of both worlds: single-threaded control plane, multi-core data plane.

You can use the [`crypto-async`](https://github.com/jorangreef/crypto-async) module to execute zero-copy cipher, hash, and HMAC operations asynchronously in Node's threadpool for multi-core throughput without blocking the event loop.